# Failed to open the Group Policy Object -Windows 7 Administrator

Tags: windows-7, group-policy

Whenever I try to access the Local Group Policy Editor (or access the local security Policy from the Administrative tools folder) I get the following message:

> "Failed to open the Group Policy
>   Object on this computer. You may not
>   have appropriate rights.
>
> Details: Unspecified Error"

Please can somebody suggest what the problem might be?

I have used a registry cleaner, which might have done the damage.

---

### Details

I am using Windows 7 Professional as the Administrator. The PC is freestanding - no domain controller.

**Looked in the Administrative Events Log and found plenty of these:**

```
Log Name:      System
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-GroupPolicy
Date:          28/05/2011 23:43:08
Event ID:      1096
Task Category: None
Level:         Error
Keywords:      
User:          Study\The Administrator
Computer:      Study
Description:
The processing of Group Policy failed. Windows could not apply the registry-based policy settings for the Group Policy object LocalGPO. Group Policy settings will not be resolved until this event is resolved. View the event details for more information on the file name and path that caused the failure.
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-GroupPolicy" Guid="{AEA1B4FA-97D1-45F2-A64C-4D69FFFD92C9}" />
    <EventID>1096</EventID>
    <Version>0</Version>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Opcode>1</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x8000000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2011-05-28T22:43:08.750000000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>8415697</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation ActivityID="{2B1F7048-0A0F-4367-AF18-DAA5F16B73A6}" />
    <Execution ProcessID="728" ThreadID="3040" />
    <Channel>System</Channel>
    <Computer>Study</Computer>
    <Security UserID="S-1-5-21-2954353469-387026828-152714653-1014" />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data Name="SupportInfo1">2</Data>
    <Data Name="SupportInfo2">1232</Data>
    <Data Name="ProcessingMode">2</Data>
    <Data Name="ProcessingTimeInMilliseconds">390</Data>
    <Data Name="ErrorCode">13</Data>
    <Data Name="ErrorDescription">The data is invalid. </Data>
    <Data Name="DCName">
    </Data>
    <Data Name="GPOCNName">LocalGPO</Data>
    <Data Name="FilePath">C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy\User\registry.pol</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

**Also found loads of these, but don't know if this is relevant:**

```
Log Name:      System
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-DistributedCOM
Date:          28/05/2011 23:37:36
Event ID:      10016
Task Category: None
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          NETWORK SERVICE
Computer:      Study
Description:
The application-specific permission settings do not grant Local Activation permission for the COM Server application with CLSID 
{BC866CF2-5486-41F7-B46B-9AA49CF3EBB1}
 and APPID 
{066FCC09-2096-4EEF-AA2F-353DB80F1BF8}
 to the user NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE SID (S-1-5-20) from address LocalHost (Using LRPC). This security permission can be modified using the Component Services administrative tool.
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-DistributedCOM" Guid="{1B562E86-B7AA-4131-BADC-B6F3A001407E}" EventSourceName="DCOM" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="49152">10016</EventID>
    <Version>0</Version>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2011-05-28T22:37:36.000000000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>8415679</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation />
    <Execution ProcessID="0" ThreadID="0" />
    <Channel>System</Channel>
    <Computer>Study</Computer>
    <Security UserID="S-1-5-20" />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data Name="param1">application-specific</Data>
    <Data Name="param2">Local</Data>
    <Data Name="param3">Activation</Data>
    <Data Name="param4">{BC866CF2-5486-41F7-B46B-9AA49CF3EBB1}</Data>
    <Data Name="param5">{066FCC09-2096-4EEF-AA2F-353DB80F1BF8}</Data>
    <Data Name="param6">NT AUTHORITY</Data>
    <Data Name="param7">NETWORK SERVICE</Data>
    <Data Name="param8">S-1-5-20</Data>
    <Data Name="param9">LocalHost (Using LRPC)</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

Answer (score 14):

I deleted the machine GPO .pol file under c:\windows\system32\GroupPolicy\Machine

I had to show hidden files and folders first.

I rebooted and it recreated a new local policy.  Now domain GPO policies apply without fail.

Comment: Thank you so much - this was close enough for me to fix it. The problem was fixed by deleting the .pol file in the user folder instead. What a relief! This has been messing up my computer for months.

Comment: This fixed my "issue" as well.

Comment: Worked for me, too. But the new .pol file was not created in my case. I was not able to open to the Local Security Policy app on server 2012, but now I can. Probably need to set up some policies again.